# Create native Excel XLS and XLSX files from scratch and export directly to a PDF file

Tags: 7, files

We are considering migrating a Cold Fusion application to Drupal and I am wondering if the below 2 capabilities that are current Cold Fusion application is doing can be done within Drupal 7.

1. The ability to create native Excel XLS and XLSX files (NOT HTML tables that Excel has to convert each time it opens) from scratch. This includes the ability to use native Excel functions, formatting, and multiple tabs/sheets. CFSPREADSHEET makes this a relatively simple task for us.
2. The ability to export directly to a PDF file. CFPDF and CFCONTENT makes this almost as simple as wrapping the desired output in a set of tags and it’s done in many cases.

Answer (score 1):

- [PHPExcel](https://drupal.org/project/phpexcel). It uses [PHPExcel library](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) and supports native Excel export, import. We are using it in our project and it does it well.

> The PHPExcel module allows developers to export/import data to/from real Excel files.

- [Print](https://drupal.org/project/print). It allows you to generate the printer-friendly, PDF, EPUB and Email versions of any node. It supports following libraries:

  - [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)
  - [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/) (only in the 7.x-2.x branch)
  - [TCPDF](http://tcpdf.sourceforge.net/)
  - [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)

I'd recommend using the wkhtmltopdf library, since I'm using it an it creates a way better results than the others.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a loads of PDF's using PHP and if you need to do anything complicated (particularly with tables) dompdf just can't handle it so I've stopped using it all together.

I've had great success with [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) however I know a colleague has been using [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/) for some really complicated ones (tables with dynamic content that may or may not break over multiple pages).

I agree with Елин that PHPExcel is the best choice for excel files.